# Lee's algorithm for convex hull of a simple closed polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon, envelope, convex

I need a fast algorithm to find the convex hull of large simple closed polygons.

The algorithm of Lee (as described in [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tmchan/deque_latin.pdf), Section 2.1) is fine in most, but not all cases.
For instance, the clockwise polygon (3,3)-(1,2)-(2,1)-(2,2)-(3,0)-(0,1)-(0,3)-(3,3) will be given the solution (3,3)-(2,1)-(0,1)-(0,3)-(3,3) -- which does not include all vertices.

The error is that (2,2) is put on the stack. I can't see how to modify Lee's algorithm to correct for this. Can you?

Of course I could instead use Melkman's algorithm, but Lee's takes advantage of my conditions, making it so much simpler and faster that I, if possible, would prefer it. Also, I am astonished that Lee's algorithm in the literature is said to be correct.

Comment: Lee's algorithm is OK. Show your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! For Lee's algorithm I used this code (which did not work correctly in all circumstances):

Comment: Which code? There's no link.

Comment: Sorry, not used to submitting code on this site. Does it work this way? [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Convex hull.cpp]

Comment: The last function -- where I made a time and memory saving implemention of Melkman's algorithm, always works fine.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmaqciq16tm1t2f/Convex%20hull.cpp?dl=0

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure it's the right algorithm. Preparata and Shamos have a very different version of Lee's algorithm and it makes more sense to me. You can find it on [google books](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=_p3eBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA167&ots=BaYxv429gW&dq=%22lee's%20algorithm%22%20%22convex%20hull%22%20%22polygon%22&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=%22lee's%20algorithm%22%20%22convex%20hull%22%20%22polygon%22&f=false)

Comment: I may have used a bad description of Lee's algorithm. Thank you for a better reference!

Comment: @PAF: I know this is an old post. Anyway, I was working on Melkman's algorithm and spotted a serious flaw that is found in most implementations: the first three vertices musn't be aligned, otherwise the iterations go wild. The cure is to skip aligned vertices in the initialization. This may look like a rare, unimportant case, but when the polygon is a path from a digital image it is the rule rather than the exception !

Comment: Thank you! In my application alignment is very rare / should not occur, but I will include code to handle it just in case.